# Adobe CQ- Is it possible to execute CURL command?

Tags: curl, aem

I haven't worked in CQ but I am working with another team that uses CQ hence need to know if CQ supports REST commands (Something like below done using CURL)? I need to invoke an external REST webservice from CQ via HTTP request.

Note: I have asked this question to CQ team but haven't got the answer yet hence thought of checking in this forum..

```
curl -X PUT -H 'Content-type: application/json' -d '{"period": 300,"type": "crawl","start_time": "2011-03-18T12:10:32-0700","active": true}' http://localhost:8888/api/collections/collection1/datasources/8/schedule
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you say "invoke an external REST webservice from CQ" it looks like you want your code, running in CQ, to make requests to another server via HTTP.

If that's correct, you can use the HTTP client from http://hc.apache.org/ for example, it is available out of the box in CQ. The Apache Sling integration testing code makes extensive use of that, see for example the tests under https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/sling/trunk/launchpad/integration-tests

You can also use any HTTP or REST client library in CQ, provided that library is OSGi-friendly. For some of them it's very easy as they are provided as OSGi bundles, for others more initial assembly is required.

Answer (score 4):

Curl is a command-line HTTP client and CQ is based on the Apache Sling framework, supporting RESTful HTTP requests, so the answer is: yes, you can use curl to create, read, update and delete content from the CQ repository. Sling documentation provides [comprehensive information](http://sling.apache.org/documentation/bundles/manipulating-content-the-slingpostservlet-servlets-post.html) on this subject.

Please find some examples below:

Create new resource

```
curl -u admin:admin -Ftitle="some title" -Ftext="some content" http://localhost:4502/tmp/new_resource
```

Read existing resource in JSON or XML format

```
curl -u admin:admin http://localhost:4502/tmp/new_resource.json
curl -u admin:admin http://localhost:4502/tmp/new_resource.xml
```

Update existing resource

```
curl -u admin:admin -Ftitle="new title" http://localhost:4502/tmp/new_resource
```

Delete resource

```
curl -u admin:admin -X DELETE http://localhost:4502/tmp/new_resource
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use cURL, however, it certainly doesn't mean you should for this use case. cURL is generally used for Continuous Delivery automation with Jenkins, Bamboo or equivalent, or by puppet to automate standing up a new server.

It is intended as an administrative tool for a production environment, rather than receiving/serving data from the JCR.

If you are exposing cURL, you need to consider who can access it, and at what authentication levels. Also remember that you are sending the admin username and password in plaintext. At the very least, you should use an SSL certificate to authenticate the request.

Another way of approaching this, is via a post to a sling servlet. That way, you can verify transactions that come through, and authenticate through more standard methods, and gives you a higher degree of control.

Comment: I disagree with "cURL is generally used for Continuous Delivery automation", that's just one of its many uses.

Comment: Yes, I would agree there are other uses for cURL outside of CD, however, would you not consider it dangerous to use it as a method for an external system to push data into the JCR? Happy to be told otherwise, but we have always considered it far too flexible a tool to leave open to external systems in a production environment. I would have thought a transactional model provides a greater degree of control for what data enters, where, and under what conditions.

Comment: If you have a system that accepts HTTP requests, whether those come from a browser, curl or any other tool does not make a difference. It's the server's internal access control mechanisms that will make it secure or not. If such a server is on a public network, you have to be careful about which parts of the server's URL space you expose, which is in general controlled using CQ's dispatcher component or similar tools.